# File Upload with C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, ftp

I currently have a file upload working from C# directly to my server using ftpwebrequest. It works fine. However, I am very concerned about having my ftp credentials stored in my application - So I would like to upload a file to a PHP file on my server.

I've looked around at various code samples, but none have really worked. 
What I like about my current code, which other code doesn't offer is that I can report the progress to the background worker.

---

I have found this code:
C#

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                web.UploadFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpAddress + "upload1.php", fileToUpload);
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
            }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//check whether the folder the exists

$connection='ftp.mysite.com';

if(!(file_exists($connection)))
{
  //create the folder
  mkdir($connection);
  //give permission to the folder
  chmod($connection, 0777);
}

//check whether the file exists
if (file_exists($connection. $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
else
{
  //move the file into the new folder
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$connection. $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

}

?>
```

There are two things here I would like help with:
Firstly, I get an exception during upload saying I'm not logged in. I'm guessing I need to provide credentials on the php file - but I couldn't get it to work.

Secondly, How do I in cooperate the background worker report progress?

Comment: You haven't even initiated a connection or provided login credentials. Have a look at `ftp_connect()` and `ftp_login()`. http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: I am still getting invalid login details - however, it doesn't seem to be coming from the server but from my application. It highlights the line: 'web.uploadFile' as where the login details are missing....